# How to read and loop through each rows in an Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to read an excel file and loop through the rows.  I used the below code to read the excel file. But I am not getting the entire row, inseatd of getting the column values.

```
try
{
    OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
    string queryString = string.Format("Select * from [{0}$]", strSheetName, objConnection);

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, objConnection);
    objConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {

        var val1 = reader[0].ToString(); //Here I want to get each row
    }
    reader.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I need to check if the row is empty or not, if not empty, I need to serach for some values in a particular column.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can't.  You can loop through all the columns, though

Comment: Did you try your code? What is wrong? reader[0] reads the first column of the current row and at the next loop your code will read the column zero of the next row until the end of the data

Comment: @Steve, I am  trying to loop through the rows.ie, get the first row, check for a particular string, if exist process it, its kind of row validation

Comment: When you enter the while loop your reader is positioned on the first row. You could look at the values in the columns using the indexer [0] means the first column. There is no way to look at the entire row without checking column by column. Unless you know in which column the search string is.

Comment: Thanks Steve, in that case I cannot use the above code. I need to come out with another solution

Comment: @slaks.. thanks for the confirmation

Comment: I would suggest using a third-party library to read the Excel file instead of using OLE DB.  You will have much more flexibility that way.

Comment: I found a work around. ie, save the excel file as .csv file. Use the StreamReader class ReadLine() method, loop through the rows. This is not a  direct solution, but it works for me